# Can I test all 3 combinations in a drop down using Selenium Webdriver on JAVA platform?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

This what I have for a single select option at a time

```
WebElement address = driver.findElement(By.id("package-rooms"));
 Select ab=new Select(address);
 ab.selectByVisibleText("1");
```

But once the above code is done, i want to execute the 2nd and 3rd options. I don't want write separate test cases. I am pretty new in selenium. Please help....Thank you!

Comment: Means do you want multi selection at the same time??

Comment: Let us know your issue clearly.

Comment: You haven't specify what testing platform you are using but generally, combining multiple pieces of functionality is not a good practice as it becomes less clear what components of your application are failing. If you don't have any strict constraints that prevent you from having more tests, just create a separate test for each item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code if you want to select all the options of dropdown:

```
    WebElement address = driver.findElement(By.id("package-rooms"));
    Select ab=new Select(address);
    List<WebElement> list = ab.getOptions();
    for(Webelement ele : list){
        ab.selectByVisibleText(ele.getText());
    }
```

Hope it helps.